# Remove duplicate documents from a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of documents. It has columns 'title', 'description' and 'body'.

Using Python, I need to find all rows that share the same title and description, and only keep the rows that match that have the longest body if the titles and descriptions match.

For example, if I had:

| title | description | body |
| --- | --- | --- |
| My Document | a doc | this is a |
| My Document | this doc | writing is fun |
| My Document | a doc | this is a document |
| My Document | a doc | this is a document i wrote |
| My Doc 2 | another doc | documents are cool |

I would want to end up with:

| title | description | body |
| --- | --- | --- |
| My Document | this doc | writing is fun |
| My Document | a doc | this is a document i wrote |
| My Doc 2 | another doc | documents are cool |

- As you can see, any row where both title and description are the same have been filtered, leaving only the row that has the longest body length *

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the string length of column `body` by [`.str.len()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html), then group these string lengths by `title` and `description` and use [`.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) to get the indices of the maximum entry within the group.  Finally, use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to locate the rows of these max. entries.

```
df.loc[df['body'].str.len().groupby([df['title'], df['description']], sort=False).idxmax()]
```

Result:

```
         title  description                        body
3  My Document        a doc  this is a document i wrote
1  My Document     this doc              writing is fun
4     My Doc 2  another doc          documents are cool
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary column with body length, sort the dataframe and drop the duplicates (keeping only the record with largest body):

```py
df = (
    df.assign(tmp=df.body.str.len())
    .sort_values(by="tmp")
    .drop_duplicates(subset=["title", "description"], keep="last")
    .drop(columns="tmp")
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         title  description                        body
1  My Document     this doc              writing is fun
4     My Doc 2  another doc          documents are cool
3  My Document        a doc  this is a document i wrote
```

Answer (score 0):

An option via [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values) with a [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy-vectorize) key to sort by longest body length without the need for a temp column:

```
new_df = (
    df.sort_values(by='body', key=np.vectorize(len))
        .drop_duplicates(subset=["title", "description"], keep="last")
)
```

`new_df`:

```
         title  description                        body
1  My Document     this doc              writing is fun
4     My Doc 2  another doc          documents are cool
3  My Document        a doc  this is a document i wrote
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'title': ['My Document', 'My Document', 'My Document', 'My Document',
              'My Doc 2'],
    'description': ['a doc', 'this doc', 'a doc', 'a doc', 'another doc'],
    'body': ['this is a', 'writing is fun', 'this is a document',
             'this is a document i wrote', 'documents are cool']
})

new_df = (
    df.sort_values(by='body', key=np.vectorize(len))
        .drop_duplicates(subset=["title", "description"], keep="last")
)

print(new_df)
```